# Is there any free reverse DNS lookup service (DNS replication)?

Tags: dns, lookup

I want to find all domain names that were resolved for a specific IP.

How to do such a search? There is any free service/tool for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one I find most effective in returning the largest number of domains at the moment is [yougetsignal](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/)'s. [RUS-CERT](http://cert.uni-stuttgart.de/stats/dns-replication.php)'s used to be better but has been moved and doesn't seem to return so much now.

(My emphasis is tracking malware domains, so I don't know if they are more or less effective for other sorts of job.)

This functionality (storing previously-looked-up domains for reverse lookup later) is sometimes known as ‘DNS replication’. ‘Reverse DNS’ generally refers to [rDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) (PTR lookups), which only give you a single canonical name for an IP.

Answer (score 2):

[GuerrillaDNS](http://www.guerrilladns.com/) does that.

> Ever been wondering how many domains
>   your webhosting company hosts on a
>   single server? Or do you want to keep
>   track of your competitors new
>   websites?
>
> You can get this information with
>   GuerrillaDNS.com. Our great free
>   service to do Reverse DNS Lookups. It
>   has never been easier to find out
>   which domains are hosted on a
>   particular IP or server.

Comment: excelent, unfortunately the list is incomplete

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.domaintools.com/reverse-ip/

Comment: partial list: free, full list is paid

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://tools.web-max.ca/websitesonip.php#results) can help you.

and this [page](http://tools.web-max.ca/findwebsitesip.php) help you find domain name ip.

Comment: didn't work for me